# How to detect when not shipping available for current address in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently building a payment plugin for wooCommerce and I'm having a difficult time detecting when the user's address is not amongst the store's shipping addresses. Using the default payment options, this would hide the `proceed` button so the user can't proceed with the purchase. Please is a hook or event I can listen to in order hide my own custom button when selected shipping address doesn't match any available address.

Thank you